# Add a point to the Moore plane to get a normal space

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I've got the following question, and I'm having trouble with it. I was hoping that someone here could help me.

> Show that by adding one point to the Moore plane $\mathbf{M}$ one can obtain a normal space of which $\mathbf{M}$ is a subspace.

My definition of the Moore plane is just like on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane). That is, as a set $\mathbf{M} = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \geq 0 \}$, the points $(x,y)$ for $y > 0$ have as basic open neighborhoods the usual open discs centered at $(x,y)$, and the points $(x,0)$ have as basic open neighborhoods open discs of radius $r>0$ centered at $(x,r)$ together with the point $(x,0)$.

I know that $\mathbf{M}$ is not normal (and for us normal implies Hausdorff), since, for example, the closed sets $A = \{ (x,0) : x \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ and $B = \{ (x,0) : x \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q} \}$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets. I know that $A$ and $B$ cannot both be closed in this new space. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to add a point to $\mathbb{M}$ to get a normal space.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If $M$ were locally compact, I'd have a candidate... (It is not, though)

Comment: I guess that the space $(\Bbb M^*,\tau)$, constructed as follows, is normal. Pick a point $p\not\in\Bbb M$ and define a topology $\tau$ on the set $\Bbb M^*=\Bbb M\cup\{p\}$ consisting of all sets $U$ such that $U$ is open in $\Bbb M$ or $U\ni p$, $U\setminus\{p\}$ is  open in $\Bbb M$ and a set $\Bbb R_0\setminus U$ is finite, where $\Bbb R_0=\Bbb R\times\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexRavsky, that seems to make sense. I've been working on this and I think I can show that the space is normal with the assumption of regularity. But I can't seem to figure out how to show it is regular. Do you have any ideas? Or maybe a full answer? ;-)